# Show yfield in millions in ColumnChart

Tags: apache-flex

I am new to flex and creating dashboard. I am using column chart. And the values on the y-axis is very high. Is there a way to show that in millions. I understand that it must be some property for scale. However unable to find it. Please help.Thanks.

Ravi Kumar Singh

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is a way to customize axis labels.

Checkout the livedocs at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/charts_displayingdata_06.html#329984 for more information on this topic.

Cheers